# Как сделать условие, чтоб пользователь ввёл число а не текст?

Tags: java

Коллеги, добрый день. У меня есть код, в котором проводится проверка какое число ввёл пользователь, и далее выполняется вывод на экран допустим этого числа. Как сделать в else if проверку, где будет выполняться код в случае, когда пользователь ввёл текст? Код выглядит примерно вот так:

Примечание: В похожем вопросе я не нашёл нужного мне ответа.

```
if (input >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + input + " теперь содержит значение " + input2);
    } else if (input > 100 || input <0) {
        System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 100");
    }
```

Comment: посмотрите, что такое регулярные выражения

Comment: Что происходить в программе, если пользователь ввёл число?

Comment: if (input >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + input + " теперь содержит значение " + input2);

Comment: А именно System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + input + " теперь содержит значение " + input2);

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не совсем ясно, что такое `input` и `input2`, откуда они берутся, каким образом мне воспроизвести вашу проблему? Сделайте [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Вы хотите сделать проверку, какие данные ввел пользователь, но показываете участок кода, где `input` скорей всего уже является числом. Выглядит так, что приведенного кода недостаточно, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос. Пожалуйста, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1461783/edit) ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для ввода используется `Scanner`, следует проверить, содержит ли ввод число при помощи `Scanner::hasNextInt()`/`Scanner::hasNextDouble()`, и в случае отсутствия числа вывести соответствующее сообщение, "проглотив" некорректный ввод.

Также следует исправить условия в представленном коде, так как он не проверяет верхнее ограничение, чтобы input <= 100.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Введите число: ");
while (!sc.hasNextInt() && sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + sc.next());
}
int input = sc.nextInt();

if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
    System.out.println("Корректно введенное значение " + input);
} else {
    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 100");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш код работает корректно, то `input` это число.
Следовательно при вводе текста будет выдано исключение, просто обработайте его при вводе;

```
    try { int input = название.nextInt();
       *Тут ваш код*
       }
      catch (InputMismatchException err) {   //Ловим ошибку ввода
        System.out.print("Вы отправили текст"); //Тут будет выполнен код, если введен текст
        }
```

Тут можно подробно прочитать про исключения
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html
(Гугл переводчик отлично переводит)

Comment: Да, Вы правы, но я пока еще не работал с исключениями, есть ли какой то способ поставить условие if, чтоб в input вводился исключительно определённый текст, а при вводе всего остального работал блок if?

Comment: @SALUTE, вообще-то в [моем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1461875/386633) и приведен образец такого кода, где проверяется соответствие ввода целому числу.

Comment: Через  else if не выйдет. Если вы введете строку в числовой сканнер произойдет исключение, хотя я не знаю что у вас за сканнер. Было бы неплохо предоставить код сканнера

Answer (score -1):

Да не нужны тут регулярки ,банальные коды аски если ввод англ , или utf если ввод русский, цифры в аски, ну собственно аски часть utf. Диапазон кодов проверяете,  в таком то диапазоне цифры  , в другом буквы. Более того в обёртке char Character есть функции проверки символа на то буква ли это или цифра. Ну естественно перед этим вы разбиваете весь ввод по символами,  и в зависимости от проверки на вхождения в тот или иной диапазон либо в зависимости от результата функций Character выполняете ваши действия . Регулярки это уровень людей по опытней, новичкам сначала нужно что-то базовое как понимания char utf кодировки и т.п. Все эти вещи хорошо объясняются в книге шилдт java руководство для начинающих   как раз в начале, листать много не надо

Comment: А можете пожалуйста на примере кода показать моего?

Comment: Я на работе, не могу. Книгу откройте которую я вам указал.  Полистайте первые главы, там у него в начале кучу примеров консольных программ с разбором ввода, как раз по вашей теме.

Comment: Прочёл начало книги, но нужной мне информации я не обнаружил