# Java вывод меню. Возвращение к главному меню

Tags: java

Всем добрый день. Я бы хотел спросить как после выполнения определённого момента кода через оператор switch он возвращался в главное меню? Например

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    
        System.out.println("Choise whats you wanna. ");
        System.out.println("If you wanna vektor tap \"1\".");
        System.out.println("If you wanna Snowman tap \"2\".");
        System.out.println("If you wanna stop tap \"0\".");
        int choise = sc.nextInt();
        boolean end = false;
        do {
        switch(choise) {
        case 1:vektor();
            break;      
        case 2: Snowman.main(); //это лежит в отдельном файле  
        break;
        case 0: end = true;
        break;
        default: System.out.println("Inncorect value ");
        }
        }while(!end );
            
    }
И что бы после выполнения кода в case 1 он возвращался обратно в меню для выбора.
```

Comment: Я, кажется, недавно давал ответ на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475862/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f/1475937#1475937

Answer (score 1):

Вывести меню в отдельный метод, и вызывать его в конце нужного case. Выглядит примерно так:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       menu();
    }
    public static void menu(){
        
        System.out.println("Choise whats you wanna. ");
        System.out.println("If you wanna vektor tap \"1\".");
        System.out.println("If you wanna Snowman tap \"2\".");
        System.out.println("If you wanna stop tap \"0\".");
        int choise = sc.nextInt();
        boolean end = false;
        do {
            switch(choise) {
                case 1:vektor();
                menu();             // <--- Возврат к основному меню
                    break;
                case 2: Snowman.main(); //это лежит в отдельном файле
                    break;
                case 0: end = true;
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("Inncorect value ");
            }
        }while(!end );
    }
}
```

И дальше, в зависимости от логики вашей программы, выбираете пункты, в которых нужно организовывать выход либо возврат в основное меню

Comment: я понял что вы имеете ввиду но не особо что выходит. То есть у нужно ещё добавить menu() в сами методы например в класс Snowman (в сам код)? Правильно?

Comment: Ну если вам после выполнения Snowman нужно снова вернутся в главное меню - добавьте menu() в case после вызова Snowman. Кроме того, если вы планируете добавить вызов главного меню во все пункты кроме выхода, то вам и do - while уже не нужно будет. Распишите конкрентно, что не именно не выходит, и как вы хотите видеть принцип работы программы. В коде, который я выше привел, только сама идея отображена

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае проще будет внести вывод меню в тело цикла. Также рекомендуется использовать более лаконичную стрелочную форму записи `switch`, официально существующую с Java 14.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);          
    boolean end = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please select your option: ");
        System.out.println("Tap \"1\" for vektor.");
        System.out.println("Tap \"2\" for Snowman.");
        System.out.println("Tap \"0\" to exit.");
        
        switch (sc.nextInt()) {
            case 1 -> vektor();   
            case 2 -> Snowman.main();
            case 0 -> end = true;
            default -> System.out.println("Incorrect value ");
        }
    } while(!end);
}
```